# grunt-contrib-watch with LiveReload not working

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I cannot get LiveReload to work with Grunt. I am using grunt-contrib-watch. While Grunt is watching the stated files, nothing is reloading in the browser. So I will see:

```
Running "watch" task
Completed in 0.203s at Thu Nov 21 2013 00:59:59 GMT-0500 (EST) - Waiting...
OK
>> File "views/index.html" changed.
```

But the browser window does not update. I am using LiveReload 2.0.9. Any suggestions on how to get it running?

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  'use strict';

  grunt.initConfig({
    express: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          script: './app.js'
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      tasks:  [ 'express:dev' ],
      options: {
        livereload: true,
        nospawn: true
      },
      files: [
        './views/index.html',
        './preprocessing/css/style.scss'
      ]
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express-server');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  grunt.registerTask('default', [ 'express:dev', 'watch' ]);
};
```

Comment: Did you install the liveReload browser plugin? is it enabled?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks all you're missing is [including the livereload script in your document](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#enabling-live-reload-in-your-html): `<script src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>` by default.

If you want to avoid having to do this manually, you can use the [**connect-livereload**](https://github.com/intesso/connect-livereload) middleware.

[Here's a sample **Gruntfile.js**](https://gist.github.com/adion/7580522) that's setup for watching and livereloading using the middleware I linked to.

Comment: Any ideas why your sample wouldn't work out of the box?  I get the `Cannot GET /` message when trying that Github Gist you posted.

Comment: I found that if you use `grunt watch:<mytheme>` for some reason the server does not start listening on port 35729. If you instead run `grunt watch` it works. I have not bothered to determine why.

Answer (score 0):

If you won't add livereload.js to pages.You could use chrome plugin :

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei.

Using this plugin .when page load ,click the plugin ico ,make sure that dot changed.Then page source will auto add

Comment: the plugin you are referring to is related to a commercial product, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is older but I got this info from another website and it seemed to work regarding the question as I was having the same problem, essentially adding 
keepAlive:true to the options object will work 
here is the code

```
grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
develop: {
  server: {
    file: 'bin/www'
  }
},
watch: {
  options: {
    nospawn: true,
    livereload: reloadPort
  },
  server: {
    files: [
      'bin/www',
      'app.js',
      'routes/*.js'
    ],
    tasks: ['develop', 'delayed-livereload']
  },
  js: {
    files: ['public/js/*.js'],
    options: {
      livereload: reloadPort,
      keepAlive:true
    }
  },
  css: {
    files: [
      'public/css/*.css'
    ],
    options: {
      livereload: reloadPort,
        keepAlive:true
    }
  },
  views: {
    files: ['views/*.ejs'],
    options: {
      livereload: reloadPort,
        keepAlive:true
    }
  }
}
```

});

Comment: There is no keepalive option in watch - https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch

Answer (score -1):

You can use for Grunt [Live Reload Browser Page](https://live-reload-browser-page.com/)

[GitHub](https://github.com/Yuriy-Svetlov/live-reload-bp)

[image: Live Reload Browser Page]

Sample example

```
const 
  LiveReload = require("live-reload-bp");
  // webServer = require('./web-server');

var 
  liveReload;

// webServer();

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
  
    liveReload: {
      run: {
        options: {
          host: '127.0.0.1',
          port: '8080'
        }
      },    
      js: {
        options: {}
      },
    },

    uglify: {
        build777: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'src',
            src: 'js/**/*.js',
            dest: 'dest'
          }]
        }
    },

    watch: {
      options: {
        spawn: false 
        // It is recommended to disable `false` or not use 'grunt-contrib-watch' 
        // or perhaps even Grunt. Because it works very very slowly.
      },
      js: {
          files: ['src/**/*.js'],
          tasks: ['uglify', 'liveReload:js']
      },       
    },

  });


  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');


  // Register Task
  grunt.registerTask('start', ['liveReload:run', 'watch']);


  grunt.registerMultiTask('liveReload', '', function() {
      if (grunt.fail.errorcount > 0 || grunt.fail.warncount > 0) {
          return false;
      }

      if(this.target === 'run'){
          liveReload = new LiveReload(this.data.options);
          liveReload.run();
      }else{
          liveReload.reloadPage();
      }
  });

}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to remember 2 ports:

1. The port where Grunt is executed
2. The port where livereload is executed

When you run it:

```
$ grunt
```

This runs in : `http://0.0.0.0:9000`

The configuration that works for me in Gruntfile.js is:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
grunt.initConfig({
    connect: {
        server: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                base: '/Users/pedroce/Documents/dev/node/fipa/fipa/'
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        project: {
            files: ['public/**/*.js', 'public/**/*.html', 'public/**/*.json', 'public/**/*.css'],
            options: {
                livereload: true,
            }
        }
    }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect', 'watch']);
});
```

If you can see, the server will run in `http://localhost:9000`, but we haven't defined where livereload will run, so by default it will run in `http://localhost:35729/livereload.js`

Don't forget that in your HTML, the Firefox Add-on is:

```
(livereload, [link][1]), inserta

<script src="http://localhost:9000/livereload.js"></script>
```

Therefore you have to protect against this. Filling in your HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>some</title>
    ....
    <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
</head>
```

Finally, in the console:

```
$ grunt
```

Address in your navigator:

```
http://localhost:9000
```

When you edit any CSS archive (Or JavaScript or HTML), it should reload automatically.

Comment: Why the downvotes? This is a comprehensive answer that is technically correct.